# Automatically run javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have an html file on my desktop that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function sendCalls(){
     //Network calls
   }
</script>

</head>
<body>  
</body>
</html>
```

(I replaced my network calls with //Network calls) I want the sendCalls function to automatically get called everday. This their a way to do this without deploying it to a server? Thanks.

Comment: What makes you think that the code you haven't shown us can't run without being deployed to a server?

Comment: What do you mean by "called everyday"?  Do you just want it to run when the page loads or something else?

Comment: let's be clear, you want `sendCalls()` to be **triggered** one time per day?

Comment: do you have a browser window open day and night?

Comment: It has to be javascript? I mean, what sendCalls do? it can be replicated on a batch/bat script to easyly schedule it?

Comment: I want the sendCalls() function to trigger once a day without me having to manually open the html file in a browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, javascript is not really intended for the task you are asking for. In fact, javascript is used for client side scripts, like animating a page or validations. This could work if, like tymeJV said in the comments, you open the page everyday, but this isn't very useful.

What you will need to do is write this function in a runnable script file (like php or bash) and use a scheduler to schedule a run every now and then, in your case every day.

If you're on Linux or Mac OSX, you could use Cron, which works very efficiently : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto

On Windows you can schedule tasks with the AT command : https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726974.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

No because this is just a static HTML file that runs in a browser.  It would have to be open in a browser and the `sendCalls()` method called within a `setInterval` or `setTimeout` call.  If you want to run some javascript without a browser, you might want to look into something like node.js.